# How can I append to a file in grub 2.06?

Tags: grub2

I'm building a simple operating system (github.com/aarikpokras/aarikos). I searched the entire internet and I can't seem to find a single effective method to append to a file! For some reason, when I try something like `echo "content" >> /file`, it says that there's some syntax error. I tried the same with `cat`, but it didn't help either. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why there should be one. GRUB isn't an operating system, just the world's most configurable bootloader.

Comment: in fact I'm surprised you can even make a simple command prompt in GRUB!

Comment: Well, thanks, @user253751, I'm flattered! But, how would I make some operating system with simple code (I guess) with a kernel? Because that requires C, C++ and assembly language, and I really don't like those...

Also, are you on GitHub? Because I'd really appreciate help on this if you have the time.

Comment: By using all that stuff you don't like. There's a reason most people don't write operating systems. But, you get the chance to do something unique! If you really don't like C, C++ or assembly language... how about doing the bare minimum to make the computer run Python, or something like that, and then writing your operating system in Python? Yeah, it's *weird*, but why not?

Comment: (You would be treading in uncharted territory, though. You'd have to have a decent understanding of how computers work and how Python works; you couldn't just follow a tutorial. You would basically convert the Python interpreter to be "like an operating system", so it runs by itself without any other operating system)

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Come to think of it, @user253751, that was a pretty good idea.

Comment: Well, if you can do it. I have no doubt that it's possible, but I don't know how difficult it would be. You might have to "compile" all the .py files into the operating system itself, because as an operating system writer, you can't just call `open` to open a file, you have to write `open`. Piggybacking off GRUB only works if you are still in GRUB and not writing your own OS.

Comment: Are you on github? because if you are i'd appreciate the help. I won't be pissed if you say no, even if you're on github.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not going to write an operating system for you, sorry (not in Python or any other language)

Comment: so you're not gonna collaborate with me? 'cuz that wasn't very clear, sorry. (My reading comprehension isn't the best)

Comment: no, I don't have time

Comment: ah, okay.​​ Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grub has very limited write support. Usually it just writes into a single sector, see the `save_env` ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)) command which writes into a pre-populated sector. There is also a lack of shell redirection, which is the reason for the failure.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found a way to integrate that and I’ll put you in the thanks file.